# Get form selector id from button using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, selector

This shouldn't be so hard. Thanks for any help.

I'm trying to get the id (**form:eq#**) of a parent form from with a button action.

So, a when user clicks a button, I need to be able to add the selector (eq) of the form to the button's action.

**This is part of the button function and it works:**

```
$('form:eq('+formVal+') input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
```

***IF***

formVal = a number.

That number needs to be the selector id of the form. You use, I have multiple forms on my page, all using the same jquery script, and I am trying to make sure that when you click a button within a form, the action only applies to one form, not all forms on the page.

form:eq0 triggers the first form on the page.
form:eq1 triggers the second form on the page, etc.

I need to make this dynamic.

I have been trying code along the lines of:
**formVal=$(this).parent('form').attr('id');**

...to get **formVal** that is the numeric selector number of the (parent) form.

How the heck do I do this? Thanks for any help. The complete script is here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // This button will increment the value
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get the form name
        formVal=$(this).parents("form").find('id');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('form:eq('+formVal+') input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
            $('form:eq('+formVal+') input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('form:eq('+formVal+') input[name='+fieldName+']').form.id.val(0);
        }
    });
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the form the button is in, `this.form` might also work too depending on what type of element it is.

```
$('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    var fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get the form name
    var $form=$(this).closest("form");
    //var $form=$(this.form);
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($form.find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        // Increment
        $form.find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $form.find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I know my question was a bit awkward. I am trying to GET this variable that I have arbitrarily called formVal. There is an action attached to a form button. How can I access the selector id of the parent from from that button? ...thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't do it as simple as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // This button will increment the value
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get the form name
        var form=$(this).parents("form");

        var input = form.find("input[name='"+fieldName+"']'");
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
           input.val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            form.attr("id").val(0);
        }
    });
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

As we can access the parent form, We should not access it only to get the id and use that id to look for the form again.